# Getting database-driven from questions from one model and saving answers to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm attempting to create a flexible system of database-driven forms using rails and I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around producing the actual form given the approach.

The way I'm approaching it is to have a model that serves as an index of forms (call it `MyForms`), a model that handles the questions for all the forms (call it `MyQuestions`) and a model that handles all the answers for the forms (call it `MyAnswers`).  The forms and questions have been stored to the database in the following way:

```
mysql> select * from my_forms;                                                                                                                                                   
+----+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+                                                                                                           
| id | title      | company | created_at          | updated_at          |                                                                                                           
+----+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | First_Form |       1 | 2014-11-20 20:58:53 | 2014-11-20 20:58:53 |
+----+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+


mysql> select * from questions;
+----+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | my_form_id | question_number | question_type | the_question                                                        | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |            1 |               1 | string        | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  2 |            1 |               2 | radio         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  3 |            1 |               3 | check         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  4 |            1 |               4 | radio         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  5 |            1 |               5 | text-box      | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  6 |            1 |               6 | string        | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  7 |            1 |               7 | string        | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  8 |            1 |               8 | text-box      | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  9 |            1 |               9 | check         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
| 10 |            1 |              10 | check         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
+----+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The answers database (currently empty) is structured as follows:

```
mysql> show columns in answers;
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| question_id     | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id         | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| question_number | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| the_answer      | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This way, regardless of how many forms I want to post, questions/form, or whatever their requirements, I have them up and running with minimal hassle.

Now I'm able to show the questions easily enough, using `show` in `legal_forms_controller.rb` using the following:

```
def show
  @legalform = LegalForm.find(params[:id])
  @questions = @legalform.questions
end
```

And then displaying them in the `show.html.erb` as follows

```
<% @questions.each do |client| %>
    <span><%= client.the_question %></span><br/>
<% end %>
```

But I'm struggling to figure out how I can pair those with form input fields and save them to the answers database.  I figured that getting a blank slate of answers could involve creating an answers controller and then using an `new` method, then I could use some conditionals to create the proper input type in the view, given `question type`.  However, I can't quite see how to effectively create this form and then save the data given this approach.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  (of course a response of "good god, why are you doing it this way you should do..." is also acceptable.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would instead model it as:

```
# column :label, TEXT - the text body of the question
# column :input_type, VARCHAR - maps to html input types
# ...
class Question 
    has_many :answers # since there may be several acceptable answers or options
end

# column :is_correct, BOOL
# column :text, TEXT
class Answer
    belongs_to :question
end

# Or test 
class Test
    has_many :questions
    has_many :test_scores

    # generate a test with random questions
    def self.random(seed = nil)
        # ...
    end
end

class TestScore
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :test
end
```

This allows us to reuse any question in any test and query scores by `test` & `user` (provided that you have some kind of user model).

You can also build UI's that let admins create Tests, Questions and Answers.

To administer a test you would use TestScoreController:

```
class TestScoreController
    # administer a test
    def new
        @score = TestScore.new(user_id: current_user)
        @score.test = @test = Test.random()
    end

    # corrects test
    def create
        # ...
    end

    # Show a test result
    def show
       @score = TestScore.find(params[:id]).joins(:test)
    end
end
```

And the view: `new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@score) do %>
    <%= @test.questions.each do |q| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :questions, question do |q| -%>
            <%= f.label q.label %>
            <%= QuestionHelper.input(q) %>
            <%= q.hidden_field :test_score_id, @score.id %>
        <%= end %>
    <%= end %>
<%= end %>
```

You would then create a helper method that takes a question and returns the input. I would recommend [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) as it has a DSL which makes it a snap to generate the inputs dynamically.

```
# app/helpers/question_helper
module QuestionHelper
    def self.input(question)
        case question.input_type.to_sym
        when :text
        when :radio_button
        # ..    
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: This code is intended as a rough sketch - its totally untested and not even guaranteed to run!

Comment: http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/working-with-nested-forms-and-a-many-to-many-association-in-rails-4/

Comment: Wow thanks dude!  I'll give this a shot a little later today or tomorrow so that I have the time to make sense of it.  Much appreciated!